# Django csrf_token not implementing hidden field

Tags: python, django, csrf, web-development-server

I am working in a Django project and a part of the functionality is user login, which is not working. The same piece of code was working perfectly 10 minutes ago. 
**Error:** A csrf_token was used in a template but the context did not provide the value. 
FYI, I have already tried using `render()` and `render_to_template()` but nothing works. The files 
 **views.py**

```
def login(request):
    context=RequestContext(request)
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user=auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request,user)
                return render_to_response('ProjectLogging/main.html',{'user':user, 'project_list':Project.objects.all()}, context)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login credentials.")
    return render_to_response('ProjectLogging/login.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=patterns('ProjectLogging',
    url(r'^$', 'views.login', name="index"),
    url(r'^login/$', 'views.login', name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'views.logout', name="logout"),
    url(r'^main/$','views.main', name="main"),
    url(r'^(user/?P<username>\w+)$', 'views.main'),
)
```

**login.html**

```
{%extends "base.html"%}

{%block content%}
<h1>Sign In {%if user.is_authenticated%}{{user.username}} {%else%} user {%endif%}</h1>
{%if form.errors%}
    {%for error in form.errors%}
    <p class="error">error</p>
    {%endfor%}
{%endif%}
<form action="/login/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Log In"></p>
</form>
{%endblock%}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide the `RequestContext` to the `render_to_response()` call or, as the better option, use the `render()` shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

return render(request, 'ProjectLogging/login.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I put 'context_instance=RequestContext(request)' inside 'render_to_response()' and it worked. But I don't know why. 'context' is defined in my login function and the same piece of code was working fine... :S

Comment: `context` was defined but not passed to the template.